# Get list item count from all lists on all webs of site

Tags: sharepoint

I found the following post that returns lists items from all lists on all webs within a site. I am trying to figure out how to return the list item count instead of the list items. Any assistance would be appreciated.

[JSOM dynamicly get two announcements from all lists in all webs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945251/jsom-dynamicly-get-two-announcements-from-all-lists-in-all-webs/49501279?noredirect=1#comment86006633_49501279)

UPDATE:

I am able to return details of all document libraries on a site using this:

```
function retrieveAllListProperties() {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
    this.collList = oWebsite.get_lists();
    clientContext.load(collList);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    var tCount = 0;
    var listInfo = 'Lists on the current site:' + '\n\n';
    var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oList = listEnumerator.get_current();
        if (oList.get_baseTemplate() === 101) {
            listInfo += 'URL: ' + oList.get_parentWebUrl() + '  |  Title: ' + oList.get_title() + '  |  BaseType: ' + oList.get_baseTemplate() + '  |  Count: ' + oList.get_itemCount() + '\n';
            tCount += + oList.get_itemCount();
        }
    }
    listInfo += '\nTotal Documents: ' + tCount;
    console.log(listInfo);
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

I am able to return all sites and sub sites of a site collection using this:

```
function getAllWebs(success,error)
{
    var siteUrl = '/sites/usaraf/g357';

   var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   var web = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb();
   var result = [];
   var level = 0;
   var getAllWebsInner = function(web,result,success,error) 
   {
      level++;
      var ctx = web.get_context();
      var webs = web.get_webs(); 
      ctx.load(webs,'Include(Title,ServerRelativeUrl,Webs)');
      ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < webs.get_count();i++){
                var web = webs.getItemAtIndex(i);
                result.push(web);
                if(web.get_webs().get_count() > 0) {
                   getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);
                }   
            }
            level--;
            if (level == 0 && success)
              success(result);  
        },
        error);
   };

   getAllWebsInner(web,result,success,error);    
}

getAllWebs(
 function(allwebs){
    for(var i = 0; i < allwebs.length;i++){
        console.log(allwebs[i].get_title() + "-" + allwebs[i].get_serverRelativeUrl());   
    }
 },
function(sender,args){
     console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to tie the two together so I return the following for all specified lists on all sites and sub sites.

```
Lists on the current site:

URL: /sites/usaraf-ea/visa  |  Title: Applications  |  BaseType: 101  |  Count: 24
URL: /sites/usaraf-ea/visa  |  Title: docDropOff  |  BaseType: 101  |  Count: 28
URL: /sites/usaraf-ea/visa  |  Title: docResources  |  BaseType: 101  |  Count: 5
URL: /sites/usaraf-ea/visa  |  Title: Documents  |  BaseType: 101  |  Count: 2
URL: /sites/usaraf-ea/visa  |  Title: Site Assets  |  BaseType: 101  |  Count: 23

Total Documents: 82
```

Answer (score 0):

When you got [listitem collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246724.aspx), you could call `listItems.get_count()` to return items count.

Sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var clientContext = null;
        var web = null;
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getListItemsCount, "sp.js");
        function getListItemsCount() {
            clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            web = clientContext.get_web();
            var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Child");
            var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();                        
            this.listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);
            clientContext.load(listItems, 'Include(Id)');
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                alert(listItems.get_count());
            },
            function () {
                alert('error');
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've update my question/intent if you have a moment to take a look.